# Sonarqube - Exclude a set of specific files

Tags: angularjs, sonarqube

I am using Sonar in a Angular Application for the front part.

I have many js files in my application, but i need that the Sonar ignore or exclusion my js files that ending in .spec.js, are tests unit of Angular.

I have many folders under "src/app" and inside i have many folders with the .spec.js files .

In the properties file to Sonar (sonar-project.properties), I think I can use:

```
sonar.test.exclusions=src/app/*.spec.js
```

or

```
sonar.exclusions=src/app/*.spec.js
```

But I'm not sure, in what format is the value of property.

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. You can use the sonar.exclusions property to exclude source files from analysis and the sonar.test.exclusions property to exclude unit tests. You should pass a comma-delimited list of file path patterns to these properties.

I suggest you refer [to this topic](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-patterns) to learn how to specify path patterns. Say, if you need to exclude all the .spec.js files from all the src/app directories, use this pattern:

```
**/src/app/*.spec.js
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working ok, but I have put: sonar.test.exclusions=**/*.spec.js, I wil check the documentation to understand it

Answer (score 0):

I always use `*/*.js`and it works for me for file in main dir. So just use * or ** to navigate inside your project dir.